# opacity ion-bullet, ion-slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

my ion-slides has in scss:

```
ion-slides {
    --bullet-background-active: rgb(4, 100, 52);  
    --bullet-background: rgb(255, 0, 0); 
}
```

**the question is: how can I change the default opacity of the non-active bullet? I want her in 1**

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

well you can use this way:

```
ion-slides ::ng-deep {
  .swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-bullets {
    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
      background: green;
      opacity: 1;
      &.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
        background: red;
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so the green background is for non active bullet and red background is for active bullet